# Why does grunt-contrib-less not find bootstrap variables?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, gruntjs

I'm writing a web app, and want to hook up some css `@media` queries to variables in Bootstrap. So I downloaded bootstrap and decided to let my grunt compile it, when it compiles my own `less` files.

The relevant part of my Gruntfile looks like this

```
less: { 
  dev: {
    options:{  
      paths: ['app/stylesheets', 'app/stylesheets/bootstrap'], // All the `less` files from bootstrap are placed in 'app/stylesheets/bootstrap' //  
    },  
    files: {  
      'build/pretty/style.css':'app/stylesheets/**/*.less'  
    }  
  }
}
```

But when I run grunt `grunt less:dev` it fails and outputs

```
Running "less:dev" (less) task
>> NameError: variable @alert-padding is undefined in app/stylesheets/bootstrap/alerts.less on line 10, column 12:  
>> 9 .alert {  
>> 10   padding: @alert-padding;  
>> 11   margin-bottom: @line-height-computed;  
Warning: Error compiling app/stylesheets/bootstrap/alerts.less Use --force to continue.  

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've tried every way I can imagine,

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're trying to compile every .less file in your `app/stylesheets` directory, then concatenate them into `build/pretty/style.css`. That's how the task is supposed to work.

You probably will have better luck with something like this:

```
// app/stylesheets/style.less
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";

// Now you'll have every bootstrap mixin, variable, class, etc available
```

then, in your task:

```
less: {
  dev: {
    files: {
      'build/pretty/style.css': 'app/stylesheets/style.less'
    }
  }
}
```

If you want just the variables and mixins, you could use `@import (reference) "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";` instead. This way no Bootstrap styles will be output.

Comment: Thanks gustavohenke, but now I get this error:
    Running "less:dev" (less) task
    >> ParseError: Unrecognised input in app/stylesheets/style.less on line 7, column 1:
    >> 6  */
    >> 7 @import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less"

Comment: @MartinJosefsson I don't understand, could you post your .less file somewhere?

Comment: I am getting the same "unrecognised input" problem with `@import` directives. I know it is valid LESS, but I don't understand why it's going wrong.

Comment: Make sure you add a semi-colon to the end of your imports!